# PHP Case switch (efficiency)

Tags: php

The code below ensures that when a user accesses control panel, they are ran through a quick verification process to validate what their entities are. For instance, if a user is level 1 they are only given access to video feed which means nothing else is available to them.

When I look at the code though, I can see video feed being called when case 1 and 3 are called. I would possibly enjoy an alternative to make the code more efficient.

I was told a possible array could make things a little easier but then again this is faster.

```
    switch ($_SESSION['permission']) {
        case 1: // Level 1: Video Feed
            include ("include/panels/videofeed.index.php");
            break;
        case 2: // Level 2: Announcements / Courses / Teachers
            include ("include/panels/announcements.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/courses.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/teachers.index.php");
            break;
        case 3: // Level 3: Announcements / Video Feed / Courses / Teachers / Accounts / Logs
            include ("include/panels/announcements.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/videofeed.index.php"); 
            include ("include/panels/courses.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/teachers.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/accounts.index.php");
            include ("include/panels/log.index.php");       
            break;
        case 4: // Level 4: Teachers
            include ("include/panels/teachers.index.php");          
    }
```

Comment: This is not the case when you need to make obfuscated code to win 0.0000001sec. Each developer should write the code that is easy to read, thus - easy to optimize (but not like you did it).

Comment: I'd say this looks pretty acceptable as-is, it's certainly not *inefficient* for the computer. You could probably shuffle some code around, but it doesn't seem like you can fundamentally change much.

Comment: You *should* stop using magic numbers and define some constants instead that describe the permission levels. E.g `case PERMISSION_VIDEO_FEED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist you may run *better* if you use `require_once` if its possible. 
The second point is to shorten the url it seems that its every include the same.

Maybe try to use it in a function for example:

```
$permission_id = $_SESSION['permission']

function requireModule($moduleName, $path = 'include/panels/') {
    $moduleName .= '.index.php';
    require_once($path . $moduleName);
}

// if you want you can add an arry for it:

$permissionModules = array(
    array('videofeed'),
    array('announcements', 'courses', 'teachers'),
    array('announcements', 'courses', 'teachers', 'accounts', 'log', 'videofeed'),
    array('teachers')
);

// now we can put it in a more effectiv way

if(array_key_exists($permission_id, $permissionModules)) {
    foreach($permissionModules[$permission_id] as $includes) {
        requireModule($includes);
    }
}
```

Wrong ? Correct me!

Comment: This is incredible! I forgot all about that method of fetching. I will run a few bench marks but I am favoring this a lot! It's exactly how I pictured the setup. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's fine the way it is. I think you don't mean "efficiency" when you refer to the "repeated" includes. You mean you could compact your code by using the switch fall-through.

While this might make your code smaller, it has no significant impact of efficiency (the time the script takes to run) and it will actually make the code harder to read. Leave it be.

Comment: Well efficiency would take place because the current server hosting the file(s) does not use any form of compression so less is more in my case although it all loads in 0.06 seconds.

Comment: With fall through, how would I do it without collisions? Because I know I would have to do a few switches possibly?

Comment: @tjm Certainly making the script shorter 4 lines won't make the script load measurably faster. and if when you mention compression you mention compression in the http response, that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: well in a switch, those includes in a given case are ignored unless the case is true. And you end each one with a break.  So at any point in time, php will only evaluate the cases until it finds one that is true and execute only the code for that case.  So it doesn't really matter if you have the same included file even in all 4 cases, php isn't going to actually parse them all moreso than it takes to find the next case.

Comment: @tjm That sort of micro optimization will hardly bring any measurable, much less noticeable, speed improvements. Fall throughs seem to be pretty impossible, since your cases aren't supersets of each other.

Comment: @deceze: agreed.  Unless it was like Level 1 has "a", Level 2 has "ab", level 3 has "abc" etc...fall throughs aren't really possible/feasible, and will no doubt render the code less readable even if he manages to make one happen.  @tjmoore: If you *really* want to do some sort of fallthrough, reorganize your permission system.

Comment: @Crayon Violent
Thanks for such great responses, I am always trying to better my coding structure so that I can utilize my resources at full throttle. I know a little may not be much but in my own opinion, I think those little bits add up! :)

Comment: @tjmoore: I agree in general but don't sacrifice code readability for an extra microsecond :)